# How do I access the child nodes nested inside child node in Firebase database?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Here is my database structure in firebase.

[image]

I want to access the message content under messages child.I can get the children count of the messages child ,but cannot retrieve the value of each child.

`ref2` points to my firebase instance.
I have to get all the messages from the particulat chatroom.

```
     ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        listText.add(childDataSnapshot.child("messages").child("message").getValue() + "");
                        listText.add(childDataSnapshot.child("messages").child("name").getValue() + "");
                        //   userArrayList.add(new User("" + childDataSnapshot.child("username").getValue(), "" + childDataSnapshot.child("profileURL").getValue(), ""));
                        Log.v("messag_ids", "" + childDataSnapshot.child("messages").child("Kd4TQPrAWsNY1vcid1P").child("message")); //displays the key for the node

                    }
                    lvChat.setAdapter(new ChatAdapter(ChatActivity.this, listUsername, listText));
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
```

Comment: Post your code pls

Comment: You are using the wrong references. Check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to get the message child, we need to traverse like this.

> 'Kd4TN8fuda6CArtAUo0' -> 'messages' -> 'Kd4TQPrAWsNY1vcid1P'->'message'

Try this :

```
<yourref>.child('Kd4TN8fuda6CArtAUo0').child('messages').child('Kd4TQPrAWsNY1vcid1P').child('message')
```

[image]

Refer to this link by FireBase team : [Common SQL Queries converted for the Firebase Database - The Firebase Database For SQL Developers #4](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sKFLI5FOOHs)

Comment: the values are null.

Comment: Did you check the link in my answer, its by FireBase team.

Comment: Adding to above, that video might not help you exactly solve you issue, but it'll help you house to structure you database for effective and efficient usage

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is here:

```
childDataSnapshot.child("messages").child("message")
```

You are looking for a node called `message` inside `messages` **and it doesn't exist.**

You should first have a reference with the `messages` node and then traverse all children.

First appoach is to use the methods of `DataSnapshot` to traverse the children
and access the values use:

```
ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
              for (DataSnapshot childDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                  String name = (String) childDataSnapshot.child("name").getValue();
                  //Do the same for other properties.

               }
               //......
     }
     //..
}
```

Otherwise the second approach is to use the built-in JSON-to-POJO serializer/deserializer.
You can use a `Message.class` and then use

```
ref2.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for (DataSnapshot messageSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Message message = messageSnapshot.getValue(Message.class);
            }
        }
   //..
}
```

Your `Message` class should be something like:

```
public class Message {

   String name;
   String message;
   String chatroom;

   public Message(){
     //default constructor
   }

   //Getters and setters
   //....

}
```

Comment: I tried both but no help.My ref refrence is this
 ref2 = mDatabase1.child("chatrooms").orderByChild("roomName").equalTo("s");

Comment: @GyanendraMani Your ref should be the messages nome inside the chatrooms.

Comment: something like this:
   DatabaseReference df=mDatabase.child("Kd4TN8fuda6CArtAUo0").child("messages");

        df.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
}
where mdatabse point to   mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chatrooms");

Comment: @GyanendraMani Exactely.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti can check this link out, it's the little the same but nested child inside the child node. [Here] (https://stackoverflow.com/q/62099116/11695641)

Answer (score 0):

I have more simple answer :

You will try to access the **message** node like other **nodes like chatpic**, owner etc ...
 // Ur Database reference is the parent node , when u are trying to access message as the child use the below code :

```
for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1:mainSnapShot.child("message").getChildren()){                          

                            Map<?, ?> valuex = (Map<?, ?>) dataSnapshot1.getValue();


                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(valuex.get("message").toString())) {
                                Log.i("message",valuex.get("message").toString());
                            }



                            if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(valuex.get("name").toString())) {
                                Log.i("name",valuex.get("name").toString());
                            }

                        }
```