# Capture information from FIREBASE nested child node into an array and pass it to next ViewController XCODE

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[FIREBASE image of JSON tree with nested QUESTIONS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ItNB.jpg)

```
func loadTitles(){

    databaseHandle = ref?.child("Titles").observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot: DataSnapshot) in

        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]{

            let titleName = dict["Name"] as! String
            let directorName = dict["Director"] as! String
            let releaseDate = dict["Release"] as! String
            let titleImage = dict["TitleImage"] as? String
            let titleRating = dict["Rating"] as? Int

            let title = Title(titleName: titleName, titleImage: titleImage, directorName: directorName, releaseDate: releaseDate, titleRating: titleRating)

            self.Titles.append(title)
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

This code is how I am modelling initial JSON grab from Database. This all works fine in tableview. It also has a child that contains many questions. See image for example. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ItNB.jpg)I am making a trivia game. Simple enough.

Using XCODE 9, Swift 4 and FIREBASE.

Everything was working with hardcoded data but since switching to FIREBASE I have been having trouble getting it all to function as it was.

My current issue is utilising different aspects of the same snapshot on various screens as a user navigates.

I have researched this and only half my issue is resolved. I know how to capture a snapshot from FIREBASE but what I want to actually do is the following:

1. I have a child called TITLE and within it I have values for the details of the title. Each TITLE has a child called QUESTIONBANK which then contains multiple QUESTION children that each have values: Question, Answer, Answer, Answer etc for each. Thus a TITLE can have MANY questions and each QUESTION has its own set of answers.
2. On a table view I grab the TITLES via snapshot and display them. All working fine. I push it to an array and use a model for TITLE to display them dynamically. I also set up a cache helper to allow it to be saved during a session as users go back and forth.

ISSUE!

3. I want to then allow a user to tap on a cell and travel to the actual trivia section and utilise the questions within the QUESTION BANK child of the specific TITLE. ie creating an array of questions with answers on the NEXT page using the title chosen as the reference for the QUESTION BANK node to use that is specific to that title.

The problem is once I have used the snapshot for the TITLE on one page, I am not able to then go back in and create an array of all the questions and answers for that TITLE when it is selected by the user and we move to another page.

I already created the model for this and I know it works as I hardcoded data for it BEFORE setting up FIREBASE and replacing all my hardcoded data with FIREBASE database, storage and authentication.

It has been a struggle as I am very new to all this and I now hit a wall with this latest matter. I don't want to spend days or a week trying to figure it out.

Any help appreciated on it!

Comment: here is a link to a similar issue that wasn't solved on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42268002/how-do-i-access-the-child-nodes-nested-inside-child-node-in-firebase-database

Comment: Instead of describing your data structure and code, edit your question to include the actual [minimal JSON and code that are needed to reproduce where you are stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (as text, no screenshots please). Such an MCVE is the most likely way to get help. You can get the JSON from your database by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I have added some snippets

Comment: Also is it possible to grab two levels of data from a single JSON? ie getting each title and then getting ALL the Question nodes and values associated with that title at the same time? Not that I'd want to do that, but was wondering. Ideally I want to be able to get the QUESTIONS for the chosen title on the following ViewController.

Comment: A single JSON Snapshot includes the parent key and ALL of the child nodes. So if you were to observe the snapshot in your screen shot, all of the data is loaded; Cast, Director, Name, QuestionBank and ALL of the children of QuestionBank. It's unclear what is preventing you from doing your task - if you've got that snapshot stored in an array, then you will also have access to all of the child data within that snapshot as well. Can you clarify what the actual problem is?

Comment: I am trying to get my head around grabbing those specific sections within my snapshot. ie the syntax for daisy chaining to the QUESTIONS within the QUESTIONBANK for a SPECIFIC TITLE tapped in a tableview. My design is that I take snapshot and model with TITLE that is passed to array and displayed. You tap to DETAIL VIEW of film. This TITLE doesn't know SPECIFIC child of TITLES database so that I can then pull QUESTIONS. How I grab the questions for each title AT THE SAME TIME as I take the details of the film OR get that information at the next page once a selection is made (preferable).

Comment: Thanks so much for this assistance guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer this in two ways. A specific answer to the question, and then suggest an approach using a different structure.

Given a structure of movies almost identical to yours

```
  "movies" : {
    "movie_id_0" : {
      "question_bank" : {
        "questions" : {
          "question_0" : {
            "correct_answer" : "HAL 9000",
            "question_text" : "Name of computer"
          }
        }
      },
      "title" : "2001, A Space Odyssey"
    },
    "movie_id_1" : {
      "question_bank" : {
        "questions" : {
          "question_0" : {
            "correct_answer" : "Ted Stryker",
            "question_text" : "Main character name"
          }
        }
      },
      "title" : "Airplane"
    }
  },
```

Here's the code that will read the movies node, print out each movie title and then the questions; I just did one per movie for brevity but if there were more (question_1, question_2 etc) those would print as well.

```
let ref = self.ref.child("movies")
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
    if snapshot.exists() == true {

        for movieChild in snapshot.children { //this will iterate over every movie node
            let movieSnap = movieChild as! DataSnapshot //each movie is it's own snapshot

            let movieDict = movieSnap.value as! [String: Any]
            let title = movieDict["title"] as! String
            print(title)

            let questionBank = movieSnap.childSnapshot(forPath: "question_bank")
            let questions = questionBank.childSnapshot(forPath: "questions")

            for questionChild in questions.children {
                let questionSnap = questionChild as! DataSnapshot
                let questionDict = questionSnap.value as! [String: Any]
                let question = questionDict["question_text"] as! String
                let answer = questionDict["correct_answer"] as! String
                print("  q: \(question)  a:\(answer)")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("no snapshot found")
    }
})
```

and the output

```
2001, A Space Odyssey
  q: Name of computer  a:HAL 9000
Airplane
  q: Main character name  a:Ted Stryker
```

The above code will give you access to QUESTIONS in the QUESTIONS BANK, per your original question.

Let's look at alternative structure:

The first thing to note that the question_bank has a child questions which then has child questions (q0, q1 etc). The questions node could be be eliminated and move up all child nodes

```
"movies" : {
  "movie_id_0" : {
    "question_bank" : {
      "question_0" : {
         "correct_answer" : "HAL 9000",
         "question_text" : "Name of computer"
       }
    },
  "title" : "2001, A Space Odyssey"
},
```

That's a very deep structure though and is going to be super complex to query and work with. Here's a better structure:

```
"movies" : {
   "movie_id_0" : {
      "title" : "2001, A Space Odyssey"
    },

"questions" : {
   "question_0"
      "for_movie_id": "movie_id_0"
      "correct_answer" : "HAL 9000",
      "question_text" : "Name of computer"
   "question_1"
      "for_movie_id": "movie_id_0"
      "correct_answer" : "Stanley Kubrick",
      "question_text" : "Directed by?"
```

This would allow queries for all questions for 2001, A Space Odyssey, all answers that are HAL 9000, and all movies that are directed by Stanley Kubrick.

I might even go one other step and add an inverse relationship between the movie to question

```
"movies" : {
   "movie_id_0" : {
      "title" : "2001, A Space Odyssey"
      "questions": {
         "question_0": true
         "question_1": true
    },
```

Keeping your data as flat as possible is really best practice in Firebase. Take a look at [Denormalizing is Normal](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/04/denormalizing-your-data-is-normal.html) for more insight.

Comment: wow thanks so much for this. I am going to really sit and digest it because I want to get to grips with working with Firebase. Its my real weakness. Databases. I'm new to Swift and have only been working with Firebase for a few days. Question, did you generate the ids? Movie id  and questions id? ie you didnt use childbyautoId?

Comment: @ROKOKO Please use childByAutoId in general for key names that will be iterated over (as in this case). I just used the movie_0 and question_0 id's for readability. I hope it helps - let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: This is VERY clear. I am really grateful for it. I think my next hurdle will be learning how to search specific titles by ID when I need to call on them for editing or deleting purposes. As I say this area is all very new to me.

Comment: It takes time but keep with it. If the answer helps you, make sure to accept it so it can help others.

Comment: Yes I will do. If say I want to model data on a title on one view then later on many views later I want to store new data to the title in question, is that something that I would have to have stored the title as a snapshot to be passed from view to view?

Comment: @ROKOKO That's probably going to be a good new question. Maybe this will answer though. There are several approaches; If you are keeping the data in a dataSource array, updating the data in Firebase would trigger a childChanged event. When that event fires it will be passed the changed data - which can then be used to update the dataSource array. Another option is to not watch for child changed events and when you write data to Firebase, also update the dataSource array that stored in memory. There are other ways but those are probably the most common approaches.

Comment: I managed to figure out all things and now I'm just trying to do the setup the best way possible. Ie flat and easily accessible nodes. I've been trying to get an answer on best practice for a firebase database setup but no replies yet. Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623995/firebase-data-structure-best-practice-for-user-interaction

Comment: @ROKOKO The structure I outlined above is the way to go. If you follow that pattern it will keep your Firebase denormalized, queryable and expandable. The question you posted is pretty open ended an may not get a response because of that - your structure depends on what you want to get back out of Firebase.