# Firebase Data Structure Best Practice For User Interaction

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am building a review app and wanted to figure out best practices in structuring a Firebase database to store reviews, likes and comments from users on titles and each other's posts. I am using Xcode and Swift.

1. Do I make a separate REVIEWS node that stores all reviews and has a USER ID child for the user ID of the writer of the review and a TITLE ID node for the ID of the Title being reviewed?
2. Do I nest reviews associated with the titles or users within the title and user nodes?
3. When it's time to display say all a user's reviews, do I then query the database using the user's ID?
4. For displaying all the reviews of a title do I query using the title's ID?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very difficult to give one answer because there are 100 different structures that would work. Here's a cross-linked, double referenced structure to illustrate that point

```
movies
   movie_0
     title: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail"
     reviewed_by
       uid_1: tre
     reviews
       review_0: true

reviews
   review_0
     movie_id: "movie_0"
     uid: "uid_1"
     review: "Best movie evah"

users
  uid_0
     name: "Tim"
     reviewed_movies:
       movie_0: true
     reviews
       review_0: true
```

With that crazyness, you can:

```
query movies for which users reviewed it or which reviews
query reviews for certain users, certain movies and that the actual review was
query users for names, which movies that user reviewed and what the reviews were
```

So the question is; what do you need to query for?

Lets take your #3

> When it's time to display say all a user's reviews, do I then query
>   the database using the user's ID?

The the structure I presented, if you want to get all of a users reviews, you don't have to query at all! You directly observe that users node

```
let ref = fbRef.child("users").child("uid_0").child("reviews")
ref.observe...
```

then you can iterate over the results to obtain the review references

Likewise, you could query the reviews node for all reviews where uid is the uid of the the user in question.

I realize this isn't a specific answer but it does provide guides

**EDIT**

One of the comments was a specific question so let me address it this way.

Suppose the only goal is to see all of the reviews for a specific movie. The structure could be greatly simplified:

```
movies
   movie_0
     title: "Monty Python and the Holy Grail"
reviews
   review_0
     movie_id: "movie_0"
     uid: "uid_1"
     review: "Best movie evah"
users
  uid_1
     name: "Tim"
```

Then suppose we know the movie and the movie id of movie_0. To get the reviews and the user, something like this will work

```
let reviewsRef = self.ref.child("reviews")
let query = reviewsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "movie_id").queryEqual(toValue: "movie_0")
query.observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { snapshot in
    for child in snapshot.children {
        let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
        let dict = snap.value as! [String: Any]
        let uid = dict["uid"] as! String
        let review = dict["review"] as! String

        let userRef = self.ref.child("users").child(uid)
        userRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { userSnapshot in
            let userDict = userSnapshot.value as! [String: Any]
            let userName = userDict["name"] as! String
            print("\(userName) said \(review)")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great response. So basically if I wanted to see all reviews for a particular movie I can then do that direct? I guess my real question is this, when doing the function code for saving a review I would thus be saving the review to three different locations? Users, Movies and Reviews as opposed to one Reviews node with a User and Movie ID as children.

Comment: Are you an educator of some kind? You're very clear and concise. Your previous response on accessing children nested within a node and iterating over all of them was very helpful and helped me figure out a ton more.

Comment: One thing I do not understand is the 'true' values you presented though.

Comment: I guess I am looking for the absolute simplest way to do this as I am not advanced enough with firebase to do anything fancy with my framework yet. I'm now ten days in with it!

Comment: @ROKOKO No, not an educator; Engineer & Computer science by schooling, business owner by love and programmer by *passion*. The true values allow references (uid's in this case) to be stored and accessed in Firebase as keys. You can think of 'true' as a placeholder; Firebase doesn't allow nil values so you have to have something as a value so it's common practice to use true. It could be 'a' or '1' or 'dude' - it just requires something to allow the key to be stored. If you use my structure then yes, you would have duplicate data but that's common in Firebase. I'll add some more to the answer.

Comment: Okay great I will wait to see your expanded answer. So this means to edit or delete it would have to be done in three places then

Comment: @ROKOKO Correct. The downside of duplicated data is that it takes more work to change data in one place than several. The tradeoff is expandability , maintainability and queryability. I updated my answer to address the specific use case in your first comment.

Comment: Ah understood. Well for my purposes expandability right now isn't a priority. Functionality and ease of implementation is. So if there is a simpler way of doing it, then I'd probably want to go down that route.

Comment: In other words based on the current database I have that you saw I'd probably want to just update that to incorporate reviews, likes etc rather than redo the whole structure

Comment: @ROKOKO That will have to be your call. We have not seen your current actual structure so it's hard to advise - however, it's much harder to change it later once you've 'settled in'. Making a change early in development is generally the best timing. BTo answer the question, it seems like just adding the review node will get you the functionality you want. If my answer helped be sure to accept it to it can help others!

Comment: Yes I did that and it works a charm. I feel like I owe you a beer or something because your advice is making me take leaps and bounds in figuring out issues with my design for this. I am now on scoring and I want to figure out the best way to display an average of all the ratings for each film. I however want to make sure I am not re calculating all the scores and the averages every time I got to a page and just updating the average as users add or delete or change their ratings. I think I have an Idea to do with observing child added etc. Maybe a separate Ratings node or nested in Title node.