# Unable to call values from FirebaseDatabase Realtime Using FirebaseUI

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

[image]

Above is just an example of the structure of the folder in FirebaseDatabase. 
My query is that how am I suppose to get those child node value.

Below is my code which I tried:

```
//FirebaseDatabase Collecting all the Item List
    ValueEventListener listener= new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    arrayItemList.add(ds.getKey());
               }

                firebaseRecyclerViewItem(arrayItemList);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled: Unable to fetch data");

        }
    };
    lookUpDatabase.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Here is code for the Method firebaseRecyclerViewItem():

```
public void firebaseRecyclerViewItem(final ArrayList<String> arrayItemList) {
    DatabaseReference reference = null;
    String referenceName = null;

    ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //FirebaseDatabase 2'nd Reference Address
            for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                String key1 = ds.getKey();
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + key1);

                String firebaseItemName = ds.child("DATA").getValue(String.class);
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + firebaseItemName);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayItemList.size(); i++) {

        referenceName = arrayItemList.get(i);
        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("DATA").child(referenceName);
        reference.addValueEventListener(valueEventListener);

        //Loading RecyclerView
        RecyclerViewItemList(reference, referenceName);
    }

}
```

Is not that I am not able to get the values, I am able to get it however in the database pic which I have attached there are three FILE01, FILE02 and FILE03. I am only able to get the last FILE03, "01" value, I mean ValueEventListner skips all the other FILE present there only take the Last update or the last file. But I want all the files data present there to display it on my recyclerView.

I have also tried a different approached where I get the DataSnaphot, and use the for() Loop, where I used nested loop:

```
//FirebaseDatabase Collecting all the Item List
    ValueEventListener listener= new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                // here is where the changes which I have made, I tried to called the value which is impossible but still I tried to, but not result.

                for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                   String key= ds.getKey();
                    String firebaseItemName = ds.child("DATA").getValue(String.class);
                Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + firebaseItemName);

                }
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled: Unable to fetch data");

        }
    };
    lookUpDatabase.addValueEventListener(listener);

    RecyclerViewItemList(lookUpDatabase);
```

Is there a way or a method which I can use to call the values.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag. That also has the advantage that Stack Overflow automatically highlights the code correctly.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Okay my bad, I didn't know about that.  Now I know it won't happen. Either way if you can please help me with the above query

Comment: Please relax, everyone here is a volunteer. You can hope for an answer (and already got one!), but receiving an answer is not guaranteed. Also, it is weekend and Pentecost, so people are probably still spending time with their family.

Comment: @ModusTollens I understand that. but... It's fine. Knowledge is Everything that I care about.

Comment: It was my fault that I believed I will get my solution here...

Comment: I am sorry the answer you got didn't satisfy you, but please don't blame the platform or its users. All help you get on here is free, but that also means that answers can't be insisted upon. People go thru much at times like these, that could be a reason that traffic is lower at the moment.

Comment: I am not blaming the platform or its users, I am blaming myself for believing in it.

Comment: Look at all that was achieved over the years with _voluntary work_! This platform is wonderful! But it is not a personal help desk, and if you took it for one, it's no wonder you are disappointed. Hope you'll have more luck in the future!

Answer (score 1):

You should call **notifyDataSetChanged()** in **for loop**. Otherwise your **reference** and **referenceName** will be rewrited.

So your code should be

```
 for (int i = 0; i < arrayItemList.size(); i++){
//Add your data to arraylist

rvAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

**Edit**:

This will show your firebase data. I just changed your second method.

```
/*I changed Here*/
 private ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> yourChildList = new ArrayList<>();

 ValueEventListener listener= new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        if (dataSnapshot.exists()){


            for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                /*I changed Here*/
                HashMap<String,String> dataMap = new HashMap<>();


               String key= ds.getKey();
                String firebaseItemName = ds.child("DATA").getValue(String.class);
            Log.i(TAG, "onDataChange: " + firebaseItemName);


            /*I changed Here*/
            dataMap.put(key,firebaseItemName);
            yourChildList.add(yourDataMap);

            }


            /*I changed Here
            *
            *I think this method is used to update data to your recyclerView
            *if I'm right, you can replace it
            *RecyclerViewItemList(lookUpDatabase);
            *
            */ 

            yourRecyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(yourChildList);
            yourRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            recyclerView.setAdapter(yourRecyclerAdapter);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onCancelled: Unable to fetch data");
    }
};
lookUpDatabase.addValueEventListener(listener);
```

**Note**:I don't recommend you to use nested listeners. You should avoid nested listener for better performance and maintainability. You should use **Observer** or **LiveData** to update Recyclerview.

Comment: Okay, I get that but I am still getting the last element from the database not all of the data. I want to get all the data from all of the file node

Comment: Sorry for late reply, got some work.  I am going to try that. I will let you know if it's help.

Comment: One more thing rvAdapter, which variable is it?

Comment: I am still only getting the last FILE03 value, not the FILE02, and FILE01. Those files are being not displayed

Comment: Can anyone help me solving my query. it's been 3 days from now that I have been stuck here

Comment: @Wade, I have updated my answer. Make sure your reference is on the right data node.

Comment: Okay, let me give this one a try. I will update it as soon as I get the result after I try it.

Comment: One More thing which I have forgotten to mentioned is that I am using FirebaseRecyclerView dependencies

Comment: it seems like it didn't work after I made the changes because I am using the FirebaseRecyclerView Dependencies where I have to pass the DatabaseReference

Comment: Is there any other way around? Since I am using the FirebaseRecyclerView Dependencies